# Use Mobile Broadband API for getting location details

Tags: windows-8.1, mobile-broadband-api

Can I get cellID, LAC, MNC and MCC by using Mobile Broadband API in Windows 8? I have a Windows 7 Location application which opens SIM serial port and gets the cellID, LAC, MNC and MCC details and sends those details to unwired API and gets location details. So I am trying to replicate the same using Mobile Broadband API as we should not be opening ports.
please help.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the MCC / MNC from the operator ID, via [IMbnRegistration.GetProviderId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323151(v=vs.85).aspx)

The LAC and Cell ID aren't available via Windows Mobile Broadband API.
They also appear not to be included in the standard MBIM interfaces (defined in the MBIM USBIF spec version 1.0: http://caxapa.ru/thumbs/334029/MBIM_v1_0_USBIF_FINAL.pdf and accessible via the MbnDeviceServices interfaces).